# Anime where a man / boy's pet cat is turned into a non-catgirl human

Tags: story-identification, anime

Anime, or possibly a Light Novel, where a man / boy's pet cat is turned into a non-[catgirl](https://tvtropes.org/Main/CatGirl) human. No ears, no tails. A.k.a not a [Little Bit Beastly](https://tvtropes.org/Main/LittleBitBeastly).

I think her hair's long and black?

And he's against them having sex because she's still his pet. I forget what her feelings are about it.

I think it was mentioned on TVTropes. It might have a page to itself, it might not.

The [Bestiality Is Depraved](https://tvtropes.org/Main/BestialityIsDepraved) page doesn't have what I'm looking for.

Comment: You might try searching the [Humanity Ensues](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HumanityEnsues) page.

Comment: Do you remember when you read it? *Niku Kyu!* feels a little too catgirl...

Comment: Interesting would be if the former cat completely ignored him. Like a cat might once she no longer needed you. I have seen this in cats.

Comment: @DavidW - Thanks for inducing me to take a second look! Found Inumimi! That *might* be it? Unless there's a cat-version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I was wrong, and I got confused with [Inumimi](https://tvtropes.org/Manga/Inumimi). Unless there really is a cat-version-ish out there.

> Yuichiro comes home from an exchange program in Canada and finds that his father has given human forms to his three dogs, Elga, Luna and Rino.

> Yuichiro is not romantically interested in any of them, and in fact feels uncomfortable around them because they are so human, proving that not All Men Are Perverts.

---

Or maybe I got confused with [Cat Nine](https://tvtropes.org/Webcomic/CatNine), which had a page from 2012 onwards, which is also about a pet cat turned human, and is an Animesque webcomic. The JustWokeUpThatWay wick would've caught my interest.